# Sometimes graphic issues (flickering) after resume from suspend (ThinPad X250, Kubuntu 15.10 Wily)

Tags: 16.04, graphics, kubuntu, suspend, resume

I have a ThinkPad X250 running Kubuntu 15.10. Sometimes, after resume from suspend the monitor starts flickering from time to time. After restarting the machine everything works fine again. Is there anything I can do about this?

Update:

I upgraded to 16.04 and I use the Kubuntu backports. The issue is still present.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a graphics driver issue. Intel HD Graphics drivers are installed on Ubuntu by default.

You can attempt to use a different set of newer but stable graphics drivers:

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

You could of course use the bleeding edge PPA, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Seems like the ppa only works for Precise and Trusty so far.

Comment: Yeap, you're right. You'll likely need to wait until they release for Xenial.